# Public Key Cryptosystem uncertainty

Tags: encryption

Can a party send plaintext (unencrypted i.e not ciphertext) to another party? Does all communication need to be encrypted as ciphertext?

Comment: It isn't very clear what you are asking here. Email is plain text sent between parties, in general, so it's clearly possible, but I don't think that's what you mean.

Comment: Hi Matthew. I meant under a Public Key Encryption such as RSA. Is all communication under such a system supposed to have non plain-text messages?

Comment: @daveb I am also having trouble understanding, anything can be sent as long as it can be converted into bytes? a larger description is needed please (maybe a scenario in which you think it may not work?)

Answer (score 1):

If Alice the sender has a Signing Certificate, she signs her message with her Signing Key and Bob who receives it can verify the Signature, which contains her Signing Certificate and associated key, to prove Alice sent it.

A Signature allows the message to be sent in the clear although protects its Integrity by demonstrating it has or has not been altered.

Comment: Hi Andrew  and Mike. If a person sends a ciphertext and cannot remember what they sent. Can they then send an unencrypted message to the receiver and then receive it back as an encrypted message that they can then compare against the original message they had sent

Comment: @daveb, if this is for the same Question as above, I agree with Matthew, please edit the question and provide the problem you are trying to solve. What's the larger framework, here?

Comment: @daveb that question doesn't make any sense. RSA is a public-key cryptosystem, meaning that if Person A encrypts a message for Person B, and then Person B encrypts the same plaintext for Person A, the two ciphertexts will be different. As others have said, please [edit](https://security.stackexchange.com/posts/106465/edit) your question with more details and context so we can guess what question you are *trying* to ask.

Comment: With a symmetric cipher this would be possible, but it would be far easier to ask for another copy of the shared private key and decrypt the original message. There are ways to transmit the private key securely, namely Diffie-Hellman.

Answer (score 0):

Sure, with any cryposystem you always have the option to ... not use it. For example with email-based S/MIME encryption I can send you an email with an encrypted attachment, or an unencrypted attachment. The email system doesn't care, it's just an attachment. Same for PGP-based encryption, ciphertext or plaintext, it's all just text to the email system.

That said, some corporations / government departments will have internal policy that messages which are not encrypted or signed will get blocked at the mail server. This is corporate policy and really has nothing to do with the crypto system itself.